# Recover files from broken Nexus 6

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, data-recovery, broken-screen, 5.1-lollipop, nexus-6

So a couple of weeks ago, I dun gooft, and completely destroyed my Nexus 6 screen (glass, and LCD, but the touchscreen still works). That is, I can't see what's being displayed at all, and getting it repaired isn't worth what it costs. Also, I can no longer interact with the phone. PS, I live in Australia, so Google's free replacement scheme isn't available to me.

I'd like to get the data off my phone, but NFC, developer mode, and cloud backups weren't enabled prior to me damaging the phone. The device isn't rooted either. So I think I might be screwed, as everything I've read needs one of those things to be enabled.

Is there anything that I can do to reclaim my lost data? I've got a few photos and documents that would be nice to retrieve.

Comment: You can take a look at questions tagged under [tag:broken-screen] which I believe would be helpful. Other than that, it is likely possible that you can access your device using ADB from Recovery. If that's so, then do `adb pull <SOURCE> <TARGET>` to fetch your data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Already looked into adb, but Google said I need USB debugging on for that, so I thought it a dead end.

Comment: @cjdb boot to recovery mode. In recovery mode ADB should work, even if you had it disabled.